# How to get a device/partition name of a file ?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I have partition structure like :

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       51606140 16939248  34142692  34% /
/dev/sda5         495844    72969    397275  16% /boot
/dev/sda7      113022648 57515608  49765728  50% /home
/dev/sda8     113022648 57515608  49765728  4% /mnt
```

while parsing directories content using readdir() - how to find out which file resides on what device?

readdir() invoked from root directory and parses the file name and prints its size.
like from  device  : /dev/sda6 and  list the filenames under that partition. 
When it reads contents from /home - it should display reading content from /dev/sda7 and list filenames

Please let me know,if you need more details/info

Comment: If you are calling `readdir`, someone must have called `opendir` first.  What was the path used in the call to `opendir`?

Comment: actually,the opendir() will be called on / directory.It parses the entire file system - where it faces this problem of identifying whether its crossed to different partition or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a st_dev member in struct stat, it should uniquely identify one partition.

Example in bash:

```
stat ~/.vimrc
  File: `/home2//leonard/.vimrc' -> `local-priv/vimrc'
  Size: 16              Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 6818899     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1024/ leonard)   Gid: ( 1024/ leonard)
Access: 2012-06-22 16:36:45.341371003 +0300
Modify: 2012-06-22 16:36:45.341371003 +0300
Change: 2012-06-22 16:36:45.341371003 +0300
```

The stat utility does no additional magic. Here is strace -vvv output:

```
lstat64("/home2//leonard/.vimrc", {st_dev=makedev(8, 2), st_ino=6818899, st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1024, st_gid=1024, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=16, st_atime=2012/06/22-16:36:45, st_mtime=2012/06/22-16:36:45, st_ctime=2012/06/22-16:36:45}) = 0
```

0x0802 is major 8(sd) partition 2, so /dev/sda2

In order to map this to actual partitions you can iterate /proc/mounts and stat all the devices (first column). The contents of /proc/mounts is just like the output of mount(1) except it comes directly from the kernel. Some distros symlink /etc/mtab to /proc/mounts.

Or you can parse /proc/partitions:

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1    3998720 sda1
   8        2  972762112 sda2
```

Of course /dev/sda might not actually exist, the device could be using a long udev name like /dev/disk/by-uuid/c4181217-a753-4cf3-b61d-190ee3981a3f. Major/Minor numbers should be a reliable unique identifier of a partition.

Comment: thanks, I got the major/minor(8,2) number from stat - how to get its corresponding partition name (/dev/sda2) ?

Comment: Edited to explain mapping to partition or device names.

Comment: Thanks cdleonard for the help, I can use the /proc/partitions file.

Answer (score 2):

you can just do

```
df <file_name>
```

that will give you the device and partition for the particuar file

Comment: thanks , It works with shell script , I was looking for solutions with C programming.

Comment: can't you just call the shell command from C and stream the output into a variable?

Comment: I'm looking for any library/system calls solutions (since the current code base doesn't use any shell command), If its not available , I'll go with your suggestion.Take shell command output and parse it to get the desired results.